# Bootstrap pop-up calendar in Angular 4

Tags: angular, calendar, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap pop-up calendar that I can choose different date. I would like to import specific data when I click a certain date.. I already have the table where I can import data, and I just want the entries to be updated with different date chosen.

How should I approach this?

**calendar**

```
<span>
      <form class="form-inline">
          <button (click)="myEvent($event)">Test</button>
          <span style='margin-right:1.25em; display:inline-block;'>&nbsp;</span>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input class="form-control"
               placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd"
               name="dp"
               [(ngModel)]="model"
               ngbDatepicker
               #d="ngbDatepicker">
        <button class="input-group-addon"
                (click)="d.toggle()"
                type="button">
              <img src="img/calendar-icon.svg" style="width: 0.5rem; height: 0.5rem; cursor: pointer;"/>
            </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    </form>
    </span>
```

Comment: it will be easier to use it with reactive form instead of template driven form

Comment: read the doc https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Comment: why to use reactive form for this simple case? I don't see any benefit over template driven for the problem he's facing

Comment: Useful tip: if you get feedback on your questions (e.g. off-topic or duplicate) or if the style of asking could be improved (e.g. discouraging requests for urgent treatment) then there is no need to delete the question. Just edit the question as necessary, and reply to comments as necessary. Most feedback - even if it is critical - is intended to be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got correctly your problem is you are trying to fetch some data (trigger some action) once the date selected is certain date. Am I right?

If that's the case, all you need to do is to control the event triggered when the model of the input date changes, how can you do that? with ngModel & ngModelChange.

Sample:

```
input class="form-control"
               placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd"
               name="dp"
               [ngModel]="model"
               (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)"
               ngbDatepicker
               #d="ngbDatepicker">
```

And then in the typescript file, create a method to handle every time the model gets updated:

```
onChange(date) {
   this.model = date; // This is what [()] banana box does automatically
   checkIfDateIsWhatIAmExpecting(date) // call the method to check if is the date and if so, load/fetch/do whatever you need
}
```

Comment: Hi Lora, thanks for your help. Am I supposed to declare model somewhere? I am getting an error, property 'model' does not exist on type.

Comment: yes, you need to declare the property in the file, just go with model: any; I'd be nice to have the types well defined, in the function and in the property declaration but I am not sure what type that datepicker gives you (I think is a string)